# Notepad++ html files not displaying in Chrome

Tags: html, notepad++

I'm just starting to learn to code html but when I try to open the text file with chrome it displays as a plain text file with the html code in an not as an html document like the "Hello World" test. Or if i try to launch with Chrome it opens Google home. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you save it as a .html file or as a .txt file?

Comment: How are you saving your files, as HTML or plain text? If you're on windows don't hide file extensions and look at them in windows explorer to see how they're named.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your file is saved using a `.html` extension.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>This is title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello world - this is a heading.</h1>
<hr />
<p>This is my first HTML paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The code from above leads with Chrome to the following result:

[image]

Test yourself with exercises from w3schools.com e.g.: [HTML Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/html/)